# positivity property of inner product inconsistent when underlying field is complex?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the definition of inner product, we have $\langle v, v \rangle\geq0$ for all $v \in V$. What if the underlying field is complex numbers? Then $\langle v, v \rangle\ \in \mathbf{C}$. But then how do we define a complex number to be larger than $0$?

Comment: If $z$ is a complex number, $z \geq 0$ is generally understood to mean that $z$ is real and nonnegative. That is the intended meaning in the case of the inner product definition. In general, $\langle u,v\rangle$ is complex, but if $u=v$ then it's required to be real and nonnegative.

Comment: Note that an inner product on a complex vector space [is typically defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition) in a way that guarantees that we will have $\langle v,v \rangle \in [0,\infty) \subset \Bbb R \subset \Bbb C$ for all $v \in V$.

Comment: To answer your question directly: if $z = a + bi$, then we say that $z > 0$ if $b = 0$ and $a > 0$.  If $b \neq 0$, then $0$ and $z$ are [incomparable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation $\geq$ in the definition of positivity is not meant to be a relation over $\mathbb{C}$ but rather the usual $\geq$ relation over $\mathbb{R}$.

The justification why this is indeed well-defined (i.e. why $\langle v, v \rangle \in \mathbb{R} \ \ \forall v \in V$) lies in the symmetry property for an inner produkt:
$ \langle v, v \rangle = \overline{\langle v, v \rangle}$. From that it follows immediately that $\langle v, v \rangle \in \mathbb{R}$